# updating customer's named sheet if his name is in column A

Tags: excel

i have a main sheet in which column A holds customers name and column B to H are values date brand etc
i have written a vba for just 2 sheets and its working but i want to make that script short as i will have 30 to 40 sheets afterwards...
the main idea is if A column has customer's name. copy that row which has his name, it could be multiple rows(A4,A7,A10).... and then open his sheet and paste there.
can someone help me on this

```
    Sub customersheetpaste()

'Ashraf
    A = Worksheets("Main Sheet").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 4 To A
    If Worksheets("Main Sheet").Cells(i, 1).Value = "Ashraf" Then
    Worksheets("Main Sheet").Range("B" & i & ":H" & i).Copy
    Worksheets("Ashraf").Activate
    B = Worksheets("Ashraf").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Worksheets("Ashraf").Cells(B + 1, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    Worksheets("Main Sheet").Activate
End If
'Mozam Shahid
    If Worksheets("Main Sheet").Cells(i, 1).Value = "Mozam Shahid" Then
    Worksheets("Main Sheet").Range("B" & i & ":H" & i).Copy
    Worksheets("Mozam Shahid").Activate
    B = Worksheets("Mozam Shahid").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Worksheets("Mozam Shahid").Cells(B + 1, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    Worksheets("Main Sheet").Activate

End If
Next

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main Sheet").Cells(1, 1).Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make an array of names that you want to check, or you could load the names in column A and loop through the array of names to make it quicker. Try this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub customersheetpaste()

    Dim wsMain As Worksheet
    Dim wsName As Worksheet
    Dim lrowMain As Long
    Dim lrowName As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim arr(1 To 2) As String

    Set wsMain = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main Sheet")
    lrowMain = wsMain.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    arr(1) = "Ashraf"
    arr(2) = "Mozam"

    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        For j = 4 To lrowMain
            If wsMain.Cells(j, 1).Value = arr(i) Then
                wsMain.Range("B" & j & ":H" & j).Copy
                Set wsName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(arr(i))
                With wsName
                    .Activate
                    lrowName = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                    .Cells(lrowName + 1, 1).Select
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
                End With
                wsMain.Activate
            End If
        Next
    Next

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    wsMain.Cells(1, 1).Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

@user3099345 i tired to transpose, with 3 filled cells from A4 to A:6 it works but if i select Range from A:4 to A:7 (3 filled and 4th empty cell) , it gives error of script out of range as the next cell is empty.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub customersheetpaste()

    Dim wsMain As Worksheet
    Dim wsName As Worksheet
    Dim lrowMain As Long
    Dim lrowName As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim arr As Variant

    Set wsMain = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main Sheet")
    lrowMain = wsMain.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    arr = [transpose(A4:A7)]

    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        For j = 4 To lrowMain
            If wsMain.Cells(j, 1).Value = arr(i) Then
                wsMain.Range("B" & j & ":H" & j).Copy
                Set wsName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(arr(i))
                With wsName
                    .Activate
                    lrowName = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                    .Cells(lrowName + 1, 1).Select
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

                End With
                wsMain.Activate
            End If
        Next
    Next

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    wsMain.Cells(1, 1).Select

End Sub
```